# Import 40 spread sheets using for loop

Tags: matlab, for-loop, import

The code below is a minimal working example of my problematic code. There are actually 40 spreadsheets I need to import. The code is working except that the variables `herfs`, `gamma` and `vs` are being overwritten on each loop. I need a way to index the variables so that the data does not keep getting overwritten.

```
s.AUS=1;
s.AUT=2;
s.USA=39;
s.IND=40;
fn=fieldnames(s);
for y = fn'
    file = str2mat(strcat(y,'_herf'));
    herfs = xlsread(file, 'herf');
    gamma = xlsread(file, 'gamma');
    vs = xlsread(file, 'v');
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use cell arrays (inside the loop):

```
for ii = 1:numel( fn )
    y = fn{ii}
    hrefs{ii} = xlsread(file, 'herf');
    gamma{ii} = xlsread(file, 'gamma');
    vs{ii} = xlsread(file, 'v');
end
```

Comment: @LuciusDomitiusAhenobarbus - correct. I edited my answer to reflect your comment. Thanks.